# Remove some elements from an Array in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have an other question, i have this array in Python :

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((5));
A[0] = 2;
A[1] = 3;
A[2] = 7;
A[3] = 1;
A[4] = 8;
```

And what I want to do is to delete `A[i] for i from 2 to 4` that is to say i am looking for a command like this :

`A = np.delete(A, [2:4])` but unfortunately it doesn't work because I saw the documentation here : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html but it doesn't help me.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `np.delete(A, np.s_[2:5])` works well enough for me.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it works

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is deleting the positions from numpy array you can use:

```
np.delete(A, slice(2,5))  # note that the interval is inclusive, exclusive [2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is actually, `numpy.delete`, but you need to pass the proper second argument, e.g.:

```
np.delete(A, slice(2, 4))
```